# Color labels appearing as color code in gganimate for ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, gganimate

I'm graphing data with ggplot and animating it using gganimate. I have colors as my labels and when I add a geom_label_repel() part to my graph it adds the labels but displays the colors as the color code. (Example Blue is displayed as #0000FFFF). Here is a snapshot of my animated graph.

[image: a snapshot of the animated graph]

My data is just cumulative percentages for m&m's colors in each bag.
Here is what I currently have for my ggplot() and am wondering if I have something wrong or if there is a reason why it's changing the labels from color names to the number codes.

````
df<- data.frame(x=mm_data$Bag,
                y= c(mm_data$totalp_red,mm_data$totalp_blue,
                     mm_data$totalp_orange,mm_data$totalp_yellow,
                     mm_data$totalp_brown,mm_data$totalp_green),
                group = c(rep("Red", nrow(mm_data)),
                          rep("Blue", nrow(mm_data)),
                          rep("Orange", nrow(mm_data)),
                          rep("Yellow", nrow(mm_data)),
                          rep("Brown", nrow(mm_data)),
                          rep("Green", nrow(mm_data))))
group.colors <- c( "blue3","sandybrown","green3","darkorange"
                  ,"red2","yellow")

  
ggplot(df, aes(x, y, group=group, color=group)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point() +
  geom_label_repel(label= df$group,max.overlaps = Inf)+
  scale_color_manual(values = group.colors)+
  ggtitle("Colors present in my M&M Bag") +
  ylab("Distribution percentage") +
  xlab("Bags of M&M's")+
  transition_reveal(x)```
````

Comment: fyi, while I don't know what's in `mm_data`, it looks like your `df` is a hasty way to pivot it into a long format. There are several better ways to do that, perhaps `tidyr::pivot_longer(mm_data, -Bag, names_to="group", values_to="y")`. It's really difficult to provide accurate and high-quality assistance with a question that lacks data. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269, [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info and add the missing piece: representative sample data.

Answer (score 2):

For some reason when the labels are as.character() they will show up like this. All I had to do was save them as as.factor and they appeared as "BLUE", "GREEN", "YELLOW", etc instead of the color code.

Answer (score 1):

1. Don't use `df$` in your ggplot verbs when you are referring to the same data;
2. You need `aes(..)`, even in `geom_label_repel`.

Try this.

```r
ggplot(df, aes(x, y, group=group, color=group)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point() +
  geom_label_repel(aes(label=group),max.overlaps = Inf)+
  scale_color_manual(values = group.colors)+
  ggtitle("Colors present in my M&M Bag") +
  ylab("Distribution percentage") +
  xlab("Bags of M&M's")+
  transition_reveal(x)
```