# Creating an animated reducing bar chart with gganimate

Tags: r, ggplot2, gganimate

Happy new year to all!

So, I have this basic plot of the Bernard dataset, that shows the mortality status by treatment.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(pubh)

Bernard %>% select(fate, treat, followup) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = treat, fill = fate)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "count")
```

[image]

I would like to create an animated plot that adds the variable followup (1-720 hrs) that runs backwards and shows how the count is affected.

Ofcourse, this only affects the population of people who died (i.e. reducing their count), still I am interested in the concept, not so much the output

I have tried using transition_reveal() in the following way (to no avail):

```
libary(gganimate)
Bernard %>% select(fate, treat, followup) %>%

  ggplot(aes(x = treat, fill = fate)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "count") +
  transition_reveal(-followup) +
  labs(title = "Follow-up time: {-frame_along}"
```

[image]

Any form of help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: I think you should round the time using `round()` function and I think you are good to go. I also suggest rotating the plot by adding `+coord_flip()` to the ggplot. Here is another example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74975432/6582929

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it is a long thread, so I will take some time to go over it. What I dont like about what I have so far, is that I'd prefer the bars to start from the total count at the start, and as the followup time is increased to start dropping down accordingly. This will only happen for the "dead", that is for sure.

Comment: I suggest doing it with a simple data set and sharing it so that everyone can run the code,  manipulate the structure of the plot and provide suggestions.

Comment: As far as I'm concerned the whitespace bothers you?

Comment: You can downvote my post or flag it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest using some preprocessing to turn your "flows" data points (recorded deaths) into a "stock" (current counts of living participants). There's probably a more concise way to go about this but I hope it's clear what's happening:

```
library(tidyverse)
Bernard %>%
  count(treat, fate, followup) %>%
  mutate(status = n * if_else(fate == "Alive", 1, -1)) %>%
  group_by(treat) %>%
  arrange(-followup) %>%
  mutate(alive_count = cumsum(status),
         dead_count  = max(n) - alive_count) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(treat, followup, alive_count, dead_count) %>%
  complete(treat, followup) %>%
  fill(ends_with("count")) %>%
  pivot_longer(alive_count:dead_count) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(treat, value, fill = name)) +
  geom_col() +
  transition_manual(-followup)
```

[image]

Comment: This is just about it! Thank you!!! Nevertheless, I realize there is a lot to figure out for me here: complete() and fill() I have never used before, and the same with transition_manual(). Thanks for pointing them out to me