# How do I animate the line graph using gganimate?

Tags: r, gganimate

[Dataset[Plot[Animate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4aggI.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xfWEy.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IYySu.png)

I am trying to make animation of my line chart but I am having hard time to do that. Can anyone help me with this please?

I have tried using gganimate package.

Comment: Could you lease share the code you have tried and some reproducible data using `dput`?

Comment: Please check out this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/74975432/6582929

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.